# How to disable any service windows inside Firefox?

Tags: firefox, headless, headless-browser, xvfb

I'm running Firefox under xvfb and taking webpages screenshots from it.

Is there any simple and robust way to disable any possible requests or windows that can spoil my screenshot? Like update request, security question and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This in your default prefs.js file works pretty well:

```
user_pref("browser.cache.memory.capacity", 2048);
user_pref("browser.migration.version", 1);
user_pref("browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion", 2);
user_pref("browser.sessionstore.enabled", false);
user_pref("browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash", false);
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
user_pref("browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab", false);
user_pref("extensions.enabledItems", "{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:3.6.13");
user_pref("extensions.lastAppVersion", "3.6.13");
user_pref("extensions.update.notifyUser", false);
user_pref("security.warn_entering_weak", false);
user_pref("security.warn_viewing_mixed", false);
```

default profile can be find out in profiles.ini file. Hope it helps someone)